# Sending cv2 video data over sockets and displaying it in kivy

Tags: python, image, opencv, sockets, kivy

My approach towards sending the `numpy` array of OpenCV video image frame is that I converted the array to bytes format as shown below. I actually want to display it in kivy image texture (which needs data in bytes form).

```
import socket
import cv2

IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 7878
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect( (IP , port) )
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

def capture_and_send():
    ret, frame = capture.read()

    buf1 = cv2.resize(cv2.flip(frame, 0) , (160,120))
    buf = buf1.tobytes()
    send_data = f'{len(buf):<{10}}'.encode('utf-8') + buf
    client_socket.send(send_data)

while True:
    capture_and_send()
```

Here, I used the `.tobytes()` method. The way I displayed it on server side is:

```
import socket
import select

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import threading
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture

class VedioCam(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.img=Image()
        layout = BoxLayout()
        layout.add_widget(self.img)
        #opencv2 stuffs
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_run , daemon=True)
        self.thread.start()
        return layout

    def thread_run(self):

        Header_size = 10
        IP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        port = 7878

        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server_socket.bind( (IP,port) )
        self.server_socket.listen()

        while True:
            client_socket , client_addr = self.server_socket.accept()
            message_header = client_socket.recv(10).decode('utf-8')
            message = client_socket.recv(int(message_header))

            texture1 = Texture.create(size=(160,120), colorfmt='bgr')
            texture1.blit_buffer(message, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
            self.img.texture = texture1

VedioCam().run()
```

Now, describing my actual problem. In the kivy window, the only thing I can see is a black rectangle. What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to fix the problem?

Comment: I believe the `blit_buffer` command and the `self.img.texture = texture1` must be done on the main thread. Try putting those two commands in another method that you trigger with `Clock.schedule_once()`.

Comment: Try printing the length of `message` after the `recv()`.

Comment: thanks, @John Anderson it worked fine.